# Correct plural term "recent items" in french for custom objects

Tags: salesforce

For custom or standard objects, when I click on "object" name, I have by default the recent items display.
In french, there is a mistake only for custom objects and a "s" is missing at the end of "recent" (plurial mode)
This is correct for standard object: the "s" is displayed.

I search on the help guide and the translattion configuration but nothing explains how to change this specific word displayed when you reach the object tab.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the layout of French version, though it should be the same. When you edit custom object definition there is both a Label and a Plural label field. If this was setup correctly and SF shows a singular label where plural is warranted then its a bug and a matter for salesforce customer support.